# How to use both margins of the page for a good positioning of the figures?

Tags: graphics

I have three figures, and have put them together as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\includegraphics[width = 0.7\textwidth]{AA.pdf}\enspace
\includegraphics[width = 0.7\textwidth]{CC.pdf}

\medskip

\includegraphics[width = 0.7\textwidth]{DD.pdf}

\caption{}

\end{figure}
```

which results in:

[image]

I need to keep the size of the figures as they are, that is, I cannot reduce 0.7. Is there any possibility that I can use the left margin of the page and put the two pictures in the first row in the middle of the page in a way that they use both margins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the side-by-side images in a zero-width box (using either `\makebox[0pt]{...}` or `\leavevmode\clap{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width = 0.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}\enspace
    \includegraphics[width = 0.7\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
  }%
  
  \medskip

  \includegraphics[width = 0.7\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[Note the use/location of `%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to have several figures inside a single `figure` environment, you should make them subfigures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
\quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-c}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]